# In response jsonp is overwriting the first value with the second value

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, jsonp

This is my jsonp code in which i am getting the data from online server and want to show in my 2 divs which is title and description. But the code is replacing my first div with the last content loaded by ajax_reponse.

```
function ajax_request() {
  jsonp("http://example.com/jSonApi/json_data.php", 
        "ajax_response");
}

/**Response (Called when data has been retrieved)
 *
 * @param   object  data   Javascript (JSON) data object received
 *                         through <script> request
 */
function ajax_response(data) {
  for(var key in data) {
        document.getElementById("first").innerHTML=data[key];
  }
}

function jsonp(url, callback)
{                
    if (url.indexOf("?") > -1) {
        url += "&jsonp="; 
    }
    else {
        url += "?jsonp="; 
    }
    url += callback + "&";
    url += new Date().getTime().toString(); // prevent caching        

    var script = document.createElement("script");        
    script.setAttribute("src",url);
    script.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");                
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

This is my PHP code

```
<?php 
// Connection to the database
include("connection.php");
  $startQuery = mysql_query("select * from image_gallery where recid=474") or die (mysql_error());
    if (mysql_num_rows($startQuery)>0){
      $rs=mysql_fetch_array($startQuery);
          $title = $rs["gallerytitle_en"];
          $descp =trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $rs["gallerydescp_en"]));
          $jsonData=array("data_1" => $title , "data_2" => $descp);

      }
  mysql_free_result($startQuery); 
echo $_REQUEST["jsonp"]."(".json_encode($jsonData).")";


?>
```

Comment: Use `appendChild()` method instead of `innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense that's it doing that because your code is telling it to:

```
document.getElementById("first").innerHTML=data[key];
```

Your for should be a for each:

```
for each(var key in data) {
    document.getElementById("first").innerHTML=data[key];
}
```

Your code says replace the `innerHTML` with the value you got from the server.

If your complaint is that the response is the *LAST* response then your request is being cached by the server.